# XSL generating nested list - items repeat

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Hi I have a simple XSL stylesheet that builds a nested list from a flat XML file (the file has to be flat - it's the way the software outputs it).

However at the end of the list it is repeating all items and I don't understand why. I am limited to using XSL V1.0.

XML:

```
<QueryResults ReportName="Document Hierarchy Visio" ReportID="216">
    <Data RecordCount="186">
        <DataRow index="1">
            <parentid_visio></parentid_visio>
            <childid_visio>111</childid_visio>
            <parent_id>1</parent_id>
            <child_id>1</child_id>
            <formname>Patient</formname>
            <lvl>1</lvl>
            <patrank>1</patrank>
        </DataRow>
        <DataRow index="2">
            <parentid_visio>111</parentid_visio>
            <childid_visio>213</childid_visio>
            <parent_id>1</parent_id>
            <child_id>3</child_id>
            <formname>Alias</formname>
            <lvl>2</lvl>
            <patrank>1</patrank>
        </DataRow>
        <DataRow index="3">
            <parentid_visio>111</parentid_visio>
            <childid_visio>214</childid_visio>
            <parent_id>1</parent_id>
            <child_id>4</child_id>
            <formname>Address</formname>
            <lvl>2</lvl>
            <patrank>1</patrank>
        </DataRow>
    </Data>
</QueryResults>
```

XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:key name="child" match="DataRow" use="parentid_visio" />

<xsl:template match="Data">

    <div class="tree">
        <ul>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="DataRow[not(DataRow/parentid_visio)]"/>
        </ul>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="DataRow">
           <li>
            <a href="#"><xsl:value-of select="formname"/></a>

          <xsl:if test="key('child', childid_visio)">
               <ul>
                   <xsl:apply-templates select="key('child', childid_visio)[not(DataRow/parentid_visio)]"/>
               </ul>
            </xsl:if> 

           </li>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It should be giving an output of

```
<div class="tree">
   <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Patient</a>
<ul>
            <li><a href="#">Alias</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Address</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Alert</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">GP Detail</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">School Detail</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Other Agency</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

but instead is returning:

```
<div class="tree">
   <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Patient</a><ul>
            <li><a href="#">Alias</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Address</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Alert</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">GP Detail</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">School Detail</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Other Agency</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Alias</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Address</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Alert</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">GP Detail</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">School Detail</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Other Agency</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Where am I going wrong? I am not sure why the process is repeating at the end.
This is some extra text as stackoverflow won't let me post as more detail is required apparently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with this line....

```
 <xsl:apply-templates select="DataRow[not(DataRow/parentid_visio)]"/>
```

This is saying "Select any `DataRow` that does not have a `DataRow/parentid_visio` as a child". But no `DataRow` in your XML even has a `DataRow` as a child, so it selects all rows.

So, you could change it to this, so it just checks for the `parentid_visio` as the child:

```
 <xsl:apply-templates select="DataRow[not(parentid_visio)]"/>
```

But this won't work, because this checks for the existence of the node, regardless of whether that node has text in or not, so it `<parentid_visio></parentid_visio>` returns true, and no rows are selected.

You need to do this to also check for empty `parentid_visio` nodes as well as ones that don't exist

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="DataRow[not(parentid_visio) or parentid_visio = '']"/>
```

Or this would do the same

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="DataRow[not(parentid_visio != '')]"/>
```

Or, if you knew `parentid_visio` would always exist...

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="DataRow[parentid_visio = '']"/>
```

(In this final case, if `parentid_visio` didn't exist in the XML, then `parentid_visio = ''` returns false, and so the row would not get selected).

Comment: Brilliant! I've been fiddling around and not seeing the obvious problem in front of my own nose. Thanks Tim.